# how do I write a python code for mass balance equation for a furnace by taking 3 grid points? i need to plot the density profile

Tags: python, numpy, gekko

I am new to the python. I am working on a project on thermal modeling of a furnace. for that i need to first get a density profile for the material inside the furnace using the equation : dm/dt = d(ρV)/dt = ∑m˙in - ∑m˙out + Rg. Initially, I am taking 3 grid points to solve and here is my code that I had tried. but the output I am getting is not satisfactory. please help.

I wrote the program using numpy and matplotlib.pyplot libraries.

```
''' creating grids'''
gp = np.linspace(0, L, n)
rho = np.ones(n) * rho0
drhodt = np.empty(n)
t = np.arange(0, t_final, dt)
result = np.zeros((int(t_final/dt), n))

''' computation part'''
for j in range (1, len(t)):
    plt.clf()
    for i in range (1,n-1):
        rho[0] = rho1
        rho[n - 1] = rho2
        drhodt[i] = (V_r / V) * (rho[i-1] - rho[i] + Rg)
    rho = rho + drhodt*dt
    result[j] = rho
    print(result)

    ''' plotting the values'''
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.plot(gp, rho)
    plt.axis([0, L, 0, 3000])
    plt.xlabel('distance')
    plt.ylabel('density')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.plot(t, result)
    plt.axis([0, t_final, 0, 3000])
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('density')
plt.show()
```

'''

I am expecting the outcome of the code to be 2 different profiles of density vs. gridpoints and density vs. time. but the while running the density vs time profile I am getting an error of 3 different curves which is not required. i just need one curve depicting density at different time steps.

Answer (score 1):

Are your 3 grid points in position? if so using a matrix grid would give you a better profile of what is going on. Here is an example of how you can set it up using a matrix that shows your spacial grid stepping in time. It is the second problem part A, part b and c are different methods that you can use if you have stability issues. [This is a homework that I had to do for numerical methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPMrW.jpg)